# Is there a more efficient code for adding event listeners in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Is there a way to add multiple layers in a single event listener in mapbox? I will be adding a lot more layers in the future so I expect my code will look convoluted in the future. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
map.on('click', 'lots', (e) => {
    showLotPopup(e)
});

map.on('click', 'lots-missing_data', (e) => {
    showLotPopup(e)
});

map.on('click', 'lots-appraised', (e) => {
    showLotPopup(e)
});

map.on('mouseenter', 'lots', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});

map.on('mouseenter', 'lots-missing_data', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});

map.on('mouseenter', 'lots-appraised', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});

map.on('mouseleave', 'lots', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});

map.on('mouseleave', 'lots-missing_data', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});

map.on('mouseleave', 'lots-appraised', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
const layers = [
    'lots',
    'lots-missing_data',
    'lots-appraised'
];
const fns = {
    click: e => showLotPopup(e),
    mouseenter: e => map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer',
    mouseleave: e => map.getCanvas().style.cursor = ''
};
```

Then it's either

```
Object.entries(fns).forEach(([ev, fn]) => layers.forEach(l => map.on(ev, l, fn)));
```

or

```
layers.forEach(l => Object.entries(fns).forEach(([ev, fn]) => map.on(ev, l, fn)));
```

Whichever you like better

Comment: I'm in awe! This is just brilliant! It looks elegant too.